# Show that $C_4$ is not an interval graph and every $C_n$ for $n$ $\ge 4$ is not an interval graph

Tags: group-theory

Show that $C_4$ is not an interval graph. Can you use the same argument to show every $C_n$ for $n$ $\ge 4$ is not an interval graph ?

This is my opinion :Label the vertices in $C_4$ as in figure

[image]

Assume that $C_4$ has an interval representation, because $a$ is not conneted to $c$, their interval must be disjoint, say the interval of $a$ is to the left of the one of $c$.
Since $b$ is adjacent to both both $a$ and $c$, it therefore must overlap the whole region between $a$ and $c$.
But the same also holds for $d$, so the intervals of $b$ and $d$ intersection (a contradiction).

Any graph that contains $C_n$, $n$ $\ge 4$ 
For notice that interval graphs are closed under taking induced subgraph : if we have an interval graph $G$, we can get an interval representation for any induced subgraph $G'$ of $G$ by taking one of $G$ and deleting all intervals of vertices in $G$ that are not in $G'$.

Is the opinion true ? High appriciated if someone can help me to prove this problem "that $C_4$ is not an interval graph. Can we use the same argument to show every $C_n$ for $n$ $\ge 4$ is not an interval graph ?"

Comment: Your general idea is right, but try to write it in terms of intervals. Note that if $A$ is an interval containing $b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b < c$, then $A$ contains $[b,c]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $G$ be a general graph with vertices $q_i$ and interval representation with corresponding intervals $J_i$. Note the union of two intervals with a common point is an interval. Suppose $a_1 \in J_1$ and $a_k \in J_k $. Then if there is a path $q_1q_2\dots q_k$, then $[a_1,a_k] \subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^k J_i$ and this is shown by induction.

Let $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n \in C_n$ for $n \geq 4$. Assume $C_n$ has an interval representation with corresponding intervals $I_1, I_2, \dots, I_n$. We have two paths from $p_2$ to $p_n$ and they are $p_2p_3\dots p_n$ and $p_2p_1p_n$. Let $I_2 = [a_2,b_2]$ and $I_n = [a_n,b_n]$ and WLOG assume $b_2 < a_n$. Then pick $c$ with $b_2 < c < a_n$. As $\bigcup_{i=2}^{n} I_i$ amd $I_2 \cup I_1 \cup I_n$ are intervals containing $b_2$ and $a_n$, it must also contain $c$. By construction $c \in I_1$ and $c \in I_k $ for some $k = 3,4,\dots ,n-1$. But this is a contradiction as $p_1$ is not adjacent to any such $p_i$ for $i =3,4,\dots ,n-1$.